# Post de imágenes con swift sin convertir imagenes a base64

Tags: api, post, swift4

Tengo una clase que ejecuta una API a trevés de un **URLSessionDataTask**. Agregué un protocolo para poder monitorear si existe un error o respuesta de éxito.

Todo funciona muy bien cuando ejecuto los métodos **GET** y **POST** cuando el content-type es del tipo **application/json**.

```
import UIKit

protocol NetworkManagerDelegate{
    func connectionSuccess(session: NetworkManager, response: Data, apiService: ApiService)
    func connectionWithError(session: NetworkManager, error: String, apiService: ApiService)
}

class NetworkManager: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    var delegate: NetworkManagerDelegate?
    var dataResponse: Data? //trama de bytes que se ha descargado en cada servicio
    var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    let urlDomain: String = "http://127.0.0.1"
    let client_id: String = "2"
    let client_secret: String = "kjajsnfjdsfndjfndsjnfndsfnsjf"
    let timeoutInterval: Double = 60
    var apiService: ApiService = .unknown

    func postCreateUser(withUserRegistration: UserRegistration){
      apiService = .postUserRegistration
      if dataTask != nil {
          dataTask?.cancel()
      }
      let urlStr = "\(urlDomain)/api/users"

      var jsonData: Data?
      do{
          jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(withUserRegistration)
          //let jsonString = String(bytes: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
          //print(jsonString ?? "")
      } catch let jsonErr{
          print("Error Encoding json:",jsonErr)
      }

      let headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]
      executePostURL(urlStr: urlStr, jsonData: jsonData, headers: headers)
    }


    //MARK: - Ejecución método POST de la API
     func executePostURL(urlStr: String, jsonData: Data?, headers: [String: String] ){
         let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
         let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:.main)
         var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr)!)

         var postheaders = request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
         for header in headers{
             postheaders[header.key] = header.value
         }
         request.allHTTPHeaderFields = postheaders

         request.httpMethod = "POST"
         request.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval

         if jsonData != nil {
             request.httpBody = jsonData!
         }

         dataResponse = Data() //Inicializa la trama
         dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) //Solicita la petición
         dataTask?.resume() //comenzamos con la comunicación
     }


     //Descargamos tramas de bytes
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        dataResponse?.append(data)
    }

    //Finaliza la descarga
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

        if error == nil {
            print("No hay error")
            let jsonString = String(bytes: dataResponse!, encoding: .utf8)
            print(jsonString ?? "")
            delegate?.connectionSuccess(session: self, response: dataResponse!, apiService: apiService)

        } else{
            print("Error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            delegate?.connectionWithError(session: self, error: error!.localizedDescription, apiService: apiService)
        }
    }

}
```

Necesito modificar el programa para poder enviar imágenes, pero todo lo que he encontrado convierte la imagen en base64 y la adjunta al request. Según entiendo esto consume una cantidad muy grande de recursos y es el equivalente a enviar la cadena resultante (base64) en formato JSON.

Cree un nuevo método que recibe una  instancia de **ImageForPost** que contiene la URL local del archivo, y los nombres del mismo

```
struct ImageForPost {
    var image: UIImage
    var url: URL
    var key: String
    var name: String

    init(withKey: String, withImage: UIImage, withURL: URL, withName: String) {
        self.key = withKey
        self.image = withImage
        self.url = withURL
        self.name = withName
    }
}
```

Este es el método que ejecuto desde mi vista

```
    func postAdResources(withAdId: Int, withImagesForPost: [ImageForPost] ,withAccessToken: String){
        apiService = .postAdResources
        if dataTask != nil {
            dataTask?.cancel()
        }
        let urlStr = "\(urlDomain)/api/ads/\(withAdId)/resources"

        let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer " + withAccessToken, "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data", "Accept":"application/json"]
        executePostURL(urlStr: urlStr, withImagesForPost: withImagesForPost, headers: headers)
    }
```

Y este es el método que atiende la petición con el **URLSessionDataTask**

```
//MARK: - Ejecución método POST de la API con Imagenes
    func executePostURL(urlStr: String, withImagesForPost: [ImageForPost]?, headers: [String: String] ){
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:.main)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr)!)

        var postheaders = request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
        for header in headers{
            postheaders[header.key] = header.value
        }
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = postheaders

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval

        if withImagesForPost != nil {
            for image in withImagesForPost!{
                request.setValue(image.key, forHTTPHeaderField: image.name)
                request.httpBodyStream = InputStream.init(url: image.url)
            }

        }

        dataResponse = Data() //Inicializa la trama
        dataTask = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request) //Solicita la petición
        dataTask?.resume() //comenzamos con la comunicación
    }
```